# No installation option with livecd

Tags: centos, boot, livecd

I'm currently running Windows 7 x64 Professional and want to dual-boot with CentOS.

I made a disk partitioning and wrote an image of CentOS on flash drive. But when it is being booted there's no option to install linux - only

- Boot,
- Boot(textual mode),
- Memory Test,
- Network installation and
- Boot from local drive (which is booting Windows).

I want to install linux, not to use livecd all the time, what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This posting](https://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=28350) is a bit old, but apparently the LiveCD doesn't have an "install" option. You need to get the regular install iso.

Comment: but I've done it before with liveCD and what is the most interesting - I've done it with the same iso, with the same flash drive and with the same program

Comment: I'm such a fool, this option was on the desktop - Install to hard drive

Comment: It seems someone removed my other comment. I do not see why.

Comment: I think only you and moderators are able to delete comments. maybe it was too funny=)